# What word describes the kind of words used to refer to political boundaries?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Words like kingdom, duchy, barony, empire, counties can be used to refer to land that's owned by some political entity. Is there a word that can be used to group or describe such words?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Do you want synonyms for boundaries? Borders?

Comment: http://lexfn.com/ and http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn are useful research tools for hypernyms, if a hypernym is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

**Domain**.

Defined on the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/domain) as a geographic area owned or controlled by a single person or organization.

From Middle English demeine, demain (“rule”), Old French demeine, demaine, demeigne, domaine (“power”), (French domaine), from Latin dominium (“property, right of ownership”), from dominus (“master, proprietor, owner”).

An empire is the domain of an emperor.  A kingdom is the domain of a king, A duchy is the domain of a duke, and so on.